# MadLibs overwrite inputfields

Tags: php

im trying to make a madlibs kind of game, right now i got everything working besides 1 thing. the output should overwrite the questions instead of showing above the questions. how can i manage to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
       <title>Mad Libs</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MadLibs.css">
       <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Baskerville:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
     
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <h1> MadLibs</h1>
    
            <?php
                if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
                    $Input1 = $_POST["Input1"];
                    $Input2 = $_POST["Input2"];
                    $Input3 = $_POST["Input3"];
                    $Input4 = $_POST["Input4"];
                 
    
                    echo "here is a test  $Input1. here is an other test $Input2 and again an other test 
                     $Input4 test $Input3.";
                 }else{
 <p id="Text">test question <input type="text" required name="Input1" placeholder="Enter your answer.."></p> 
        
                <p  id="Text">test question <input type="text" required name="Input2" placeholder="Enter your answer.."></p>
        
                <p  id="Text">test question<input type="text" required name="Input3" placeholder="Enter your answer.."></p>
        
                <p  id="Text">test question <input type="text" required name="Input4" placeholder="Enter your answer.."></p>
        
                <input id="Submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
            </form>
            ?>
    
           
    
        <footer>
           <p> A @2021 website</p>
        </footer>
    
     </body>
    </html>
```

The end result shows like this but the questions and the input field should be gone when the submit button is pressed

[image: end result]

Comment: If you managed to wrap part of your output into an `if` that checks a certain condition - then you should be able to wrap the other half into an `else`, hm?

Comment: (For putting plain HTML code into an if/else block, without having to output it all via `echo`, go check https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Comment: @CBroe i tried putting the p elements with the questions into an if statment, if(input == empty){p.style.display="block";}{else{p.style.display="none"; im probably doing it wrong because this doesnt work out like i expected

Comment: Why are you trying to create styles to _hide_ those elements? Just don’t _create_ them in the first place. `if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){ /* stuff here*/ } else { ?> <p>html code goes here</p> <?php }`

Comment: @CBroe okay so inside the if i already have i should add an else with the p elements with the questions in it and the button? because if i do it like this it doesnt work, i update the code with what i have rn

Comment: It does not work, because you tried to directly mix HTML into PHP now. Please go and read the links I posted. And compare what you have tried now, with what I wrote. There is a fundamental difference. Pay attention to where `<?php` and `?>` occur.

Comment: @CBroe     after the first if statement it tried using: if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] != "POST"){ and then the p elements. i do understand how the if/else statment work but i dont get how to put the p elements and the inputs inside the else of the php. i did read the things u send but i still dont really get how to put these things in the else statement

Comment: Why are you trying a second if statement, when the case you want to handle is the _exact opposite_ of the other one? That is what `else` _is for._ And I have already _shown you_ how to put the HTML code into the else, in a previous comment.

Comment: @CBroe ohh wait, i did reread the site you did send + the code and now i got it to work, thank you